# Stored procedure in SQL with count of different statement

Tags: mysql

I have 3 stored procedures, and I want to combine them into one.

I am not good at SQL, I did some searches on the internet, but was not able to get the answer.

Stored procedures are:

Stored procedure #1:

```
create procedure aquautil_test.add_Test1
     (IN orgid VARCHAR(25))
    select count(*), organization_id 
    from aquautil_test.bills 
    where status = 'Registered' and paytm_added = '1' 
    group by organization_id
```

Stored procedure #2:

```
create procedure aquautil_test.add_Test2
    (IN orgid VARCHAR(25))
    select count(*), organization_id 
    from aquautil_test.bills 
    where status = 'Registered' and paytm_added = '2' 
    group by organization_id
```

Stored procedure #3:

```
create procedure aquautil_test.add_Test3
    (IN orgid VARCHAR(25))
    select count(*), organization_id 
    from aquautil_test.bills 
    where status = 'Registered' and paytm_added = '3' 
    group by organization_id
```

How can I combine these 3 stored procedures into one?

I tried with `Case` but how to get the result? I was confuse with that

Comment: What would your desired result look like?

Comment: I only want the Count   Of all the Query

Comment: You have 3 stored procedures which produce counts based on different creteria. Are you saying you now want 1 procedure where you pass 2 parameters orgid and pytmadded so that you get 1 count based on paymt_added. Or are you saying you want 4 columns org,count(paytm_added='1'_,count(paytm_added='2'),count(paytm_added='3')?

Comment: Yes   4 columns org,count(paytm_added='1'_,count(paytm_added='2'),count(paytm_added='3')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
select organization_id,
       sum(Case when paytm_added='1' then 1 else 0 end) as 'one',
       sum(Case when paytm_added='2' then 1 else 0 end) as 'two',
       sum(Case when paytm_added='3' then 1 else 0 end) as 'three'
from aquautil_test.bills 
where status='Registered'
group by organization_id;
```

Comment: Sorry, I had superfluous , after 'three'

Comment: P.Salmon Thank you